# Import class components from a different file in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a folder called "app" which contains a "views" folder. Inside views I have a "Home.js" file in which I've defined a class component "Home". I want to use the Home class in another file "App.js".
The following code is what's in the Home.js file.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

    export class Home extends React.Component {
        render () {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text> Some text </Text>
                    <Text> Some other random text </Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

And this is what's in the App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Home } from '.app/views/Home.js';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render () {
        return (
          <Home />
        );
      }
    }
```

When I try and run it with expo, I get an error "Error: undefined Unable to resolve module '.app/views/Home.js'"
No matter the path I try to bring Home from, I get the same error, even if I copy and paste the path directly from the Home.js file. I'm curious, I wanna know if this is a code error, or maybe the way I'm bringing up the path is wrong? Any ideas as to how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Luis, knowing your full file structure would be helpful for this. Can you try `'import Home from './views/Home.js''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get in your folder like this:

```
'./app/views/Home.js';
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I actually ending up needing the curly braces to import the Home class, but other than that adding that one / helped and solved the problem. Thanks a lot! if you could edit out the part about eliminating the curly braces I'll accept your answer.

Comment: yeah you're right i didnt notice that you didnt exported default your home class